# how can i make a button that when pressed it shows the name of the product to a Text widget without using an Entry widget in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im trying to make a POS for a burger shop that when i press a button which is the product it displays the name of the product to receipt area which is Text widget without using a Entry widget

here my sample code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Login')
root.geometry('759x500+300+180')
root.resizable(0,0)


def receipt():
    
    item1 = Burger
    txt.insert(0.0, item1)
        
product1 = Button(root, text="Burger", borderwidth=2, padx=50, pady=40, command=receipt)
product1.pack()

txt = Text(root, width=30, height=20)
txt.pack()
   
root.mainloop()
```

thank you

sorry for a simple question i'm just a beginner

Comment: Did you mean `item1 = "Burger"`?  There's nothing defined with the name `Burger`, so your code as posted should have generated an error when you clicked the button.

Comment: Sorry sir im just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should pass the product to `receipt()` function as you may have more than one product to be added into the text box.

Second suggest to use `Listbox` instead of `Text`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Login')
root.geometry('+300+180')
root.resizable(0,0)


def receipt(item):
    lstbox.insert('end', item)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(side='left', fill='y')

products = ["Burger", "Apple Pie"]
for product in products:
    btn = Button(button_frame, text=product, width=15, height=3, borderwidth=2,
                 command=lambda p=product: receipt(p))
    btn.pack()

lstbox = Listbox(root, width=30, height=20, activestyle='none')
lstbox.pack(side='right')
   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you sir this is the exact output i wanted to do. thank you very much